# orientdb db.save "object is ambiguous" error

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1

I'm using release orientdb-community-2.1.9.

Following example in docs (http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Functions.html) 
I tried:

> return db.save({
>
> ```
> "@class": "V",
> log: 'test'
> ```
>
> });

And I've got this error:

> Error on parsing script at position #0: Error on execution of the script\nScript: test\n------^\nsun.org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: The choice of Java method com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.script.OScriptDocumentDatabaseWrapper.save matching JavaScript argument types (object) is ambiguous; candidate methods are: \n    class com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument save(com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.ORecord)\n    class com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument save(java.util.Map) (#360) in  at line number 360\nThe choice of Java method com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.script.OScriptDocumentDatabaseWrapper.save matching JavaScript argument types (object) is ambiguous; candidate methods are: \n    class com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument save(com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.ORecord)\n    class com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument save(java.util.Map) (#360)

How can I correct this ambiguity?

Thanks
Luca

Comment: post more details. it is not clear which language you are using. If you are using the document database you don't need to pass a class field.

Comment: Actualy I discovered it happens in a test machine with linux (ubuntu 14.04) and not in OS X!?!?

Comment: I'm using javascript, as the example does, and actually I need to specify where to put data...

Comment: Hi, could you post the entire function and your structure ?

Comment: The db's structure is very simple: create a new one, that's all! :)
As well as the function, it's a simple javascript function with nothing but code I posted at the beginning of my post:
`return db.save({
"@class": "V",
log: 'test'
});`

Comment: I have created a new javascript function with your code and it works

Comment: As I posted earlier, I guess it's a matter of OS, for me it works in OSX but not in ubuntu 14.04 server...maybe java version?

Comment: This is Java version on ubuntu machine:  `java version "1.7.0_95"  
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.4) (7u95-2.6.4-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)  
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.95-b01, mixed mode)`

Comment: Solved. It's Java version, after updated to oracle-java7 it works as documented